# How to move to the next td and check for Css class?

Tags: javascript, jquery, for-loop, html-table

I am creating a Connect 4 game and have created a table of td elements where each td has a row and col value, i.e. (1,2).
Here:

```
for(var i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
    $('table').append('<tr></tr>');
    for(var j = 0; j < cols; j++) {
    $('table').find('tr').eq(i).append('<td></td>');
    $('table').find('tr').eq(i).find('td').eq(j).attr('data-row', i).attr('data-col', j);
}
```

I also have code that assigns a css class to each td when clicked(the color changes each click as it is for 2 players). I then would like to move to td on the right side(both right, left, top and bottom in the end) and then check if that td has the similar colour class, the checker needs to go to the 4 following td's to right to find if there is a sequence of similar color td's (i.e. 3 red tds in a row doesnt achieve anything, however 4 does) I would like to use something similar to the code i already have because I can generally understand it.
Here it is, p.s. I am aware the sequence of IF statements are completely incorrect, i was using a for loop (x = 1; x < 4; x++):

```
var win = false;
if(win == false) {
    if($(this).hasClass('tdred')) {
        var colindex = parseInt($(this).attr('data-col')) + 1;
        var chosen = $('table tr').eq(colindex).find('td');
        // ^ Moves to next td right of
        //begin check if has class tdred
        if($(chosen).hasClass('tdred')) {
            x++;
            alert(data - col + "is red");
            var colindex = parseInt($(this).attr('data-col')) + 1;
            if(x = 4) {
                win == true;
            }
            if(x < 4)
        }
    } else {
        alert("not red");
    }
}
} else if(win == true)
    Alert("You win");
}
```

Hope you enjoy the horrible accumulation of if statements, I believe it is a result of pure frustration.

Comment: See [`jQuery .next()`](http://api.jquery.com/next/)

Comment: The equals in `if(x = 4)` should be `==` (or `===`). But I don't understand what you're having trouble with. Is it selecting certain cells with jQuery? You can use a selector like `td[data-row=1][data-col=2]`, for example.

Comment: Just a tip, you don't really need data-row and data-col, you can access the row- and column index directly by using: rowIndex and cellIndex on the DOM Elements tr/td, or in case you want to do it with jQuery use $('tr').index() and $('td').index(), although this would be less efficient.

Comment: I have checked out .next() and .parent() and so on but seem to differentiate - lightstyle. I like your idea @bfavaretto, however is it possible to get the data-row and data-col from the clicked td and then go (data-row + 1) so that it selects the one right of the clicked?. I will also try your method axel.michael. appreciated all thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I think that you should look at this sample for the Connect 4 game: http://www.lazylab.org/152/java/connect-four-game-coding-puzzle-algorithm-in-java/
Although it's java code, i think you could translate it into javascript